What are the text ranges in NSTextContentManager's recordEditAction?
I have a custom subclass of NSTextContentManager (and not based on NSTextStorage/NSTextContentStorage - as they are based on NSAttributedString and I'm trying to have a different store). When an edit is complete, I am trying to determine how to communicate that with the NSTextLayoutManager. I figure I have to use func recordEditAction(in originalTextRange: NSTextRange, newTextRange: NSTextRange). But, I'm having trouble figuring out what the ranges should be.
For example, if we have text "This" and I replace "s" with "". I pass an equivalent text range of (3,1) as original text range and (3,0) as newTextRange. But, this seems to throw the NSTextLayoutManager off (which still tries to lay out text in the range (3,1)).
In an effort to reverse-engineer what NSTextContentStorage does I tried the following code in a playground.
class CustomTextStorage: NSTextContentStorage {
    override func recordEditAction(in originalTextRange: NSTextRange, newTextRange: NSTextRange) {
        print("recordEditAction in \(originalTextRange) newTextRange \(newTextRange)")
        super.recordEditAction(in: originalTextRange, newTextRange: newTextRange)
    }

    override func processEditing(for textStorage: NSTextStorage, edited editMask: NSTextStorageEditActions, range newCharRange: NSRange, changeInLength delta: Int, invalidatedRange invalidatedCharRange: NSRange) {
        print("processEditing for \(textStorage) edited: \(editMask) range: \(newCharRange) changeInLength: \(delta) invalidatedRange: \(invalidatedCharRange)")
        super.processEditing(for: textStorage, edited: editMask, range: newCharRange, changeInLength: delta, invalidatedRange: invalidatedCharRange)
    }
}

let layoutManager = CustomTextLayoutManager()
let container = NSTextContainer(size: NSSize(width: 200, height: 200))
layoutManager.textContainer = container
let storage = CustomTextStorage()
storage.addTextLayoutManager(layoutManager)

storage.textStorage?.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: 0), with: "T")
storage.textStorage?.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 1, length: 0), with: "h")
storage.textStorage?.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 2, length: 0), with: "i")
storage.textStorage?.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 3, length: 0), with: "s")
storage.textStorage?.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 3, length: 1), with: "")


This outputs
processEditing for T{
} edited: [.editedCharacters] range: {0, 1} changeInLength: 1 invalidatedRange: {0, 1}
recordEditAction in 0...0 newTextRange 0...1
processEditing for Th{
} edited: [.editedCharacters] range: {1, 1} changeInLength: 1 invalidatedRange: {1, 1}
recordEditAction in 0...0 newTextRange 0...1
processEditing for Thi{
} edited: [.editedCharacters] range: {2, 1} changeInLength: 1 invalidatedRange: {2, 1}
recordEditAction in 0...0 newTextRange 0...1
processEditing for This{
} edited: [.editedCharacters] range: {3, 1} changeInLength: 1 invalidatedRange: {3, 1}
recordEditAction in 0...0 newTextRange 0...1
processEditing for Thi{
} edited: [.editedCharacters] range: {3, 0} changeInLength: -1 invalidatedRange: {3, 0}
recordEditAction in 0...0 newTextRange 0...9223372036854775807

The ranges passed to recordEditAction don't seem to be the ranges indicated by the parameter names in the func. They are always 0...0 and 0...1. When removing a character the newTextRange seems to be Int.max or similar. What are these values meant to be and what should I be passing to this?
processEditing is not available on NSTextContentManager, but, is a part of NSTextStorageObserving. This seems to have the correct ranges, and editActions passed to it. I presume this method (possibly in conjunction with recordEditAction lets the layoutManager know about the edits). How would I go about doing the same in my custom NSTextContentManager (which does not use NSTextStorage)?
